# AngularJS Error while Uploading A File

Tags: angularjs, http, file-upload

This code:

```
App.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function($http) {
   this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {

    console.log("inside upload file service js ");

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        })
        .success(function(response) {

            console.log("file uploaded sucessfully " + response);

        })
        .error(function(error) {

            console.log("Error while uploading file " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
}
```

}]);

Produces this error: "container has no method handling POST"

```
{"error":{"name":"Error","status":404,"message":"Shared class \"container\" has no method handling POST /5555-1111","statusCode":404,"stack":"Error:
```

Comment: Is your server handling post requests in the url... `uploadUrl`?

Comment: @mparnisari: Yes ,even  i am able to access container directly through url.

Comment: Yeah but accessing something usually means issuing a GET request and here you're sending POST. The server may be configured to just respond to GET requests

Comment: On same server my make Directory code is running through post. $http.post(url + '/createDirectory', {
            dirName: $rootScope.dirName
        })

Comment: What is a make directive?

Comment: sorry, its directory not directive. To create new directory.